# HTML Manual Date input with auto format

Tags: jquery, html, date, plugins

If you use input type of date in Chrome, you can enter the date manually in the input field without having to open the picker. It also shows you the format and allows you to move from Day to Month to Year using the arrow keys.

Example: http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_input_date

I'm not sure how to implement this behavior on my own. So I'm looking for a plugin that can duplicate that behavior without a picker. Some clients want to be able to enter the date by hand. We need to make sure they don't enter garbage. Also, clients are able to set their own prefered date format so we need to be able to set the format of the input field when the page loads.

I've tried googling for something like this, but keep getting results for pickers or how to enable a date picker if a browser does not support the HTML 5 date type.

We are using Bootstrap and Jquery.

Comment: Google 'javascript input masking'

Comment: Masking gets me almost there. I would like the arrow functionality as well, but just the masking will get us to our minimum requirements. I will add Masking as the answer later today if no one responds with a plugin that replicates the HTML5 behavior. Thank you Rory

Comment: To have 'the arrow' functionality you would have to use a date picker control, although they are unlikely to work well with the input mask. It's pretty much either/or, unless you can find a datepicker that does both.

Answer (score 0):

I'm marking javascript input masking as the answer as it does do mostly what I wanted. Thank you Rory.